# How to convert Visual Studio solution to Android Studio cmake?

Tags: android-studio, cmake

I have a Visual Studio project that I'm building as a shared library, which is then included in an Android Studio application. What I want to do is have everything built under Android Studio. This necessitates taking the Visual Studio solution file and converting it into a CMakelists file suitable for Android Studio.

There is a cmake-convert script, but it converts the Visual Studio solution into a CMakelists file that compiles through Visual Studio, which I don't want. I want the compilation to go through whatever C++ compile Android Studio uses.

Is there an easy way to convert either the Visual Studio solution OR the generated CMakelists file into something for Android Studio, or am I going to have to manually do the conversion?